# What method to compare of 2 matrices

Tags: matrices, algorithms, matlab

I want to **compare** 2 matrices *(for my character recognition project)*.
The idea is to say that 2 matrices are "equal" if by rotation I can superpose them. For example : $$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 255 & 255\\ 
255 & 0 & 255\\ 
 255& 255 & 0 
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
255 & 255 & 0\\ 
255 & 0 & 255\\ 
0& 255 & 255 
\end{bmatrix}$$
We can say that both matrices represent a black line on a white background and they are "equal" because we can rotate the first one to obtain the 2nd.

**For example :** [image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m312t.jpg)
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RRpC.jpg)

If I rotate the first one and superpose it on the second, it's maybe 90% equal or so. So I can say that the letter I wrote corresponds to a **B** because it matches with the template.

I saw on wiki the **correlation coefficient** but I don't know if it's the solution to my problem.. Do you know any **algorithm** or **method** to compare 2 matrices in the way I want ? Thanks !

Comment: Do you allow rotations other than $\pi/2$? Is there a problem with rotating and checking?

Comment: Any rotation is allowed ! If I want to compare B and *B* I would rotate the first B by a little angle and then it will superpose with *B* ! The main project is character recognition so I need to compare the letter with all templates. So if I wrote my letter a little bit tilt I still want to be able to compare it

Comment: Are there only square matrices involved ?  if not you could check dimensions before other math gets involved.

Comment: Nope ! Any matrices but they need to have the same dimensions. Another problem is : if I write a little letter **B** and compare to the template it will not correctly match so I need to re-scale my little **B** and I don't know how to do that..

Comment: Well, you could literally rotate the image in increments and check for similarity (e.g. Frobenius norm). But just looking at rotations seems to be rather susceptible to noise. (translations, scalings, shearings, different handwritings, etc...). Are you trying to do letter recognition? If so your approach does not seem terribly robust.

Comment: more specifically either #rows( matrix 1)=#rows(matrix 2) and #columns(matrix 1)=#columns(matrix 2)  or ,#rows( matrix 1)=#columns(matrix 2) and #rows(matrix 1)=#columns(matrix 2)  if those aren't good for rotations of 90 degrees at a time  they won't match in those cases.

Comment: Yeah my summer project it letter recognition but I wanted to do it all myself without checking how to so my idea is to compare 2 matrices (the template and the wrote one) and say if it matches close enough

Comment: Well, aside from the way I mentioned above, a nice and simple way to do this is with [Fourier Orientation Histograms](https://chrispbridge.files.wordpress.com/2016/05/rotinvpres.pdf), which provide a rotationally invariant image representation. In any case, this problem (i.e. ocr) has had an absurd amount of attention in machine learning (e.g. see [mnist](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/)), when you are later interested in the literature.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Image Processing techniques.
Something like Scale, Shift and Rotation Invariant features.

Then you should look for similarity on this feature space.